# Not understanding the benefits of using dependency injection frameworks

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

This is an honest question as I've started acquainting myself with Dagger for a java project I'm working on. I currently have this setup: I have a manager class that accepts requests, utilizes dao's to perform transactions and then responds back to the caller. This is the skeleton code that I've implemented:

```
public class MyManager {
   public Response start(Request req){
      return getDao().save(req);
   }

   public MyDao getDao() {
      return new MyDao();
   }
}

// Clients would then invoke:
// new MyManager().start(req)
```

Now if I understand correctly, I would have to introduce a new interface and module to transition to dagger. The component would look like:

```
@Component(module = MyManagerModule.class)
public interface MyManagerComponent {
   MyManger getMyManager();
}
```

and the module would look like:

```
@Module
public class MyManagerModule {
   @Provides
   public MyDao provideMyDao() {
      return new MyDao();
   }
}
```

and finally I would modify my original class to have constructor injection:

```
public class MyManager {
   @Getter
   private MyDao dao;

   @Inject
   public MyManager(MyDao dao) {
      this.dao = dao;
   }

   public Resonse start(Request req) {
      return getDao().save(req);
   }
}

// Clients now have to do:
// MyManagerComponent component = DaggerMyManagerComponent.create();
// component.getMyManager().start(req);
```

With DI, this seems much more complex. Not only do I have to create the module and interface but my client has to make a strange component and then invoke my manager from it. I'm failing to see the benefit of this. I keep hearing that this helps with unit testing but I don't understand. Before, I could easily unit test my code by simply mocking the `getDao()` method; something like

```
manager = Spy(MyManager)
manager.getDao() >> { return Mock(MyDao); }
```

I didn't really need DI to do this. Is this example to small to fully appreciate the benefits of DI?

Comment: What's the context of your code? Is this a web application? At least to me, Dagger does not seem a popular DI framework, so possibly for others some context of your code will be needed. For java web applications development, using the "Spring way" or "Java EE way", DI will offer a lot of benefits but it's only a consequence of the usage of Spring and JavaEE way.

Comment: The manager is invoked by an AWS Lambda application. I'm not sure about the popularity of Dagger, it was just a framework heavily suggested by others

Comment: "dependency injection" is really so much simpler than people make out of it. `public MyManager(MyDao dao)` _is_ `DI`. Your Dao is _injected_ via the constructor, it is not declared as `private static final ....`, for example. When `MyDao` is an interface, it is even better, you can inject whatever implementation you want. The benefits are many, but testing is the main, to me. Testing a `MyManager` when `MyDao` can be mocked - is a breeze. Also Spring, for example, can do _a lot_ of awesome things in this set-up.